# Woocommerce Checkout Field Editor - Using the choice based on the products in your shopping basket

Tags: php, wordpress, checkout

I want to create a custom choose field that displays alternatives dependent on the goods in the checkout cart. I'm using Jcodex Woocommerce Checkout Field Editor. Thus, for instance, if I have mouse and keyboard in my cart, these two things must be an option in the custom choice at checkout. How am I going to do that?

Woocommerce checkout

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to create a custom dropdown field in the WooCommerce checkout that dynamically populates options based on the items present in the cart. To achieve this, you can use a combination of custom code and hooks provided by WooCommerce.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).